# CSV to xls conversion in perl

Tags: excel, perl, csv

i wanted to parse a csv file in perl and want to generate an excel sheet.
As of now i am able to parse CSV file and converted into xls.This code is working properly, which is giving some 6 rows and 3 colums according to CSV.which is correct.After parsing it i want to do some formating also.let say any row or colum which has "Pass" as a string that should be of green color and fail then that should be of Red color.How can i do that please help..

```
     #!/run/pkg/TWW-perl-/5.8.8/bin/perl -w
     use strict;
     use warnings; 
     use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
     use Text::CSV::Simple;
     use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::Format
my $infile = "/project/ls1socdft_nobackup/rev2.0/user/Shah-       B53654/dft/dfta/perl/pattern_qa/output_0/xls_info.csv";
#usage()  unless defined $infile && -f $infile;
  my $parser = Text::CSV::Simple->new; 
  my @data = $parser->read_file($infile);
  my $headers = shift @data;

   my $outfile = shift || "/project/ls1socdft_nobackup/rev2.0/user/Shah-B53654/dft/dfta/perl/pattern_qa/output_0/xls_info.xls";
my $subject = shift || 'worksheet';

 my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($outfile);
my $bold = $workbook->add_format();
$bold->set_bold(1) ;
 my $color =$workbook->add_format(); 
 $color->set_bg_color('green'); 
 my $color1=$workbook->add_format();
 $color1->set_bg_color('red');
import_data($workbook, $subject, $headers, \@data);

# Add a worksheet
 sub import_data {
my $workbook  = shift;
my $base_name = shift ;
my $colums    = shift;
my $data      = shift;
my $limit     = shift || 50_000;
my $start_row = shift ||1;
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet($base_name);
$worksheet->add_write_handler(qr[\w], \&store_string_widths);
my $w = 1;
$worksheet->write('A' . $start_row, $colums,$bold);
my $i = $start_row;
my $qty = 0;
for my $row (@$data) {
    $qty++;
    if ($i > $limit) {
         $i = $start_row;
         $w++;
         $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("$base_name - $w");
                     $worksheet->write('A1', $colums);

          }

$worksheet->write(1+$i++,0, $row);}

   autofit_columns($worksheet);
warn "Convereted $qty rows.";
return $worksheet;
  }
 sub store_string_widths {

my $worksheet = shift;
my $col       = $_[1];
my $token     = $_[2];

# Ignore some tokens that we aren't interested in.
return if not defined $token;       # Ignore undefs.
return if $token eq '';             # Ignore blank cells.
return if ref $token eq 'ARRAY';    # Ignore array refs.
return if $token =~ /^=/;           # Ignore formula

# Ignore numbers
#return if $token =~ /^([+-]?)(?=\d|\.\d)\d*(\.\d*)?([Ee]([+-]?\d++))?$/;

# Ignore various internal and external hyperlinks. In a real scena+rio
# you may wish to track the length of the optional strings used wi+th
# urls.
return if $token =~ m{^[fh]tt?ps?://};
return if $token =~ m{^mailto:};
return if $token =~ m{^(?:in|ex)ternal:};


# We store the string width as data in the Worksheet object. We us+e
# a double underscore key name to avoid conflicts with future name +s.
#
my $old_width    = $worksheet->{__col_widths}->[$col];
my $string_width = string_width($token);

if (not defined $old_width or $string_width > $old_width) {
    # You may wish to set a minimum column width as follows.
    #return undef if $string_width < 10;

    $worksheet->{__col_widths}->[$col] = $string_width;
  }


# Return control to write();
return undef;
  }


sub string_width {

  return length $_[0];
   }
  sub autofit_columns {

my $worksheet = shift;
my $col       = 0;

for my $width (@{$worksheet->{__col_widths}}) {

    $worksheet->set_column($col, $col, $width) if $width;
    $col++;
}
 }
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm)?

Comment: sry to ask but which documentation u are talking about??

Comment: just like you are passing `$bold` to write for some cells, pass $color or $color1 to the write for the cells you want to have red or green backgrounds.

Comment: @Poojashah The documentation of `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` wich i have linked.

Comment: i tried dat also,In that case instead of perticular cell whole row is getting Red or green.In short m not able to access the individual cell.

Comment: @jens : ok i read it ...but still i will read it again

Comment: `1 + $i++` is better written as `++$i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can get the individual cell formatted the way you're expecting.

1:  Instead of passing an array of data into the $worksheet->write() method,  loop through each row and column and write each cell individually.
EX:

change

```
$worksheet->write('A1', $colums);
```

to

```
for (my $r=0;$r<@$colums;$r++) {
    for (my $c=0;$c<@{$colums->[$r]}) {
        $worksheet->write($r,$c,$colums->[$r]->[$c]);
    }
```

Now,  you can test each value being written for your criteria.  If it matches,  just include the format you want to use.

```
$worksheet->write($r,$c,$columns->[$r]->[$c],$color1);
```

}

2:  The other option is to use [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Excel-Writer-XLSX/lib/Excel/Writer/XLSX.pm)

> Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is in maintenance only mode and has
>   effectively been superseded by Excel::Writer::XLSX.

This module is more up to date and includes functions for conditional formatting,  which can be added after writing your data.
Also,  there should be no change in your excel generation code except for when you include the module and when you initialize it.
Then, you just specify the rules for the conditional formatting.

```
$worksheet->conditional_formatting( 'A1:J10',
        {
            type     => 'text',
            criteria => 'containing',
            value    => 'Pass',
            format   => $color,
        }
    );
$worksheet->conditional_formatting( 'A1:J10',
        {
            type     => 'text',
            criteria => 'containing',
            value    => 'Fail',
            format   => $color1,
        }
    );
```

Comment: I have one more question.U srsly think i should replace                      $worksheet->write('A1', $colums); as this line is wriiten for exception case

Comment: I just grabbed one of the first writes I saw and made the modification there.  If it's not the right one,  just change it to whichever line works better.  
I personally would switch to Excel::Writer::XLSX and user the conditional formatting function.